# I want to generate(or count) all possible binary matrix that satisfy certain Condition

Tags: matlab

I want to generate(or count) all possible binary matrix that satisfy below Condition.
let A be arbitrary binary matrix 4*4

> ```
> A=   [0 0 1 1]
>      [0 0 1 1]
>      [1 1 0 0]
>      [1 1 0 0] 
>
> [sum(row1) sum(r2) sum(r3) sum(r4) sum(column1) sum(c2) sum(c3) sum(c4)]
>
> condition: [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
> 1)how many matrix satisfy above condition?
> 2)how can i generate them?
>
> answer 1 is:90 
> but i want a formula or algorithm ,
> because i want to use it for 1024*1024 or upper and every arbitrary condition vector.
> ```

Comment: Do you _have_ or do you _want_ a formula/algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force approach: generate all 4x4 binary matrices and test which of them fulfill your condition:

```
condition = [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]; %// desired conditions

matrices = reshape(dec2bin(0:2^16-1,16).'-'0', 4,4,[]); %'// all binary matrices
ind = all(bsxfun(@eq, [squeeze(sum(matrices,1)); squeeze(sum(matrices,2))],...
  condition(:))); %// gives 1 for matrices that fulfill the condition, or else 0
result = matrices(:,:,ind); %// pick solution matrices
number = size(result,3); %// number of solution matrices
```

The solution matrices are `result(.,:,1)`, `result(.,:,2)`, ...; and `number` is the number of solution matrices.

You could speed this a little exploiting symmetries.

Comment: thank you luis mendo but it is not suitable for big dimension like 20*20 or upper because it should generate very very very... matrixes and ...

Comment: @user3375253 You should have specifed from the beginning the matrix sizes you need to work with. Anyway, I can't think of any approach which is not essentially brute force, sorry